# How to pass query as a parameter to stored procedure in Cosmos DB script explorer

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I want to execute the stored proc in (https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js ). To execute this one have to pass query as a parameter. My query will be like 'SELECT VALUE(c._self) FROM c Where c._ts <='+(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1))/1000.

When i'm executing above sp(mentioned in link) by passing above query as a parameter, its throwing exception. Because the sp is not accepting the above query as a parameter due to it has some function calculation.

Can anyone suggest me how can i pass the above query as a parameter.

Comment: What's the actual error message that you get back?

Answer (score 0):

Because it needs "double quotes", which are missing, as seen in your question.

More details are below:

What you need is "Script Explorer"

```
All explorers in document db are:
    "Data Explorer"
    "Document Explorer"
    "Query Explorer"
    "Script Explorer"

Click on "Script Explorer" (scroll down, it will be below "Data Explorer")
select Database on right
select Collection on right
then Stored Procedure you want to execute
then on the right there is:
    "Inputs"
        give your query like here
    "Results"
        see detailed error here
```

For example:

```
Inputs:
    SELECT c._self FROM c
Results:
    Invalid inputs.  Please ensure that the "Inputs" field contains a valid JSON value. 

Inputs:
    'SELECT c._self FROM c'     
Results:
    Invalid inputs.  Please ensure that the "Inputs" field contains a valid JSON value.

Inputs:
    "SELECT c._self FROM c"
Results:
    {"deleted":5,"continuation":false}
```

So,
1. First 2 cases failed because there are no quotes, or has single-quotes.
2. 3rd one passed because there are double quotes.

Hope that helps.